# swift json parsing, no titles for json objects

Tags: swift, codable

So I got a pretty hard problem to tackle. My JSON code has a pretty weird structure. It has the following structure:

```
{
    "title": [
        [
            "Temperature",
            "9 \u00b0C (283 \u00b0F)",
            "Good"
        ],
        [
            "Visibility",
            "10 KM (6.2 Mi)",
            "Good"
        ]
    ]
}
```

With the following code I was able to print out some easy json code:

```
import UIKit

struct WeatherItem: Decodable {
    let title: String?
    let value: String?
    let condition: String?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let jsonUrlString = "http://somelinkhere"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                let weather = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherItem.self, from: data)
                print(weather.title)
            } catch let jsonErr{
                print("error", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

But the problem is that my output for all 3 variables, title, value and condition nil is. 
I am sure I have to change the struct code, but I don't know in what way.

How do I get to JSON code with no title?

Comment: The JSON example you provided seems a bit off. I copied and paste it on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com & it says its not valid. So if you can provide JSON that is valid, it would help.

Comment: @LuisFRamirez the json is correct, it's just missing `{` and `}`

Comment: Ah, okay. Guess it was missing the brackets.

Comment: hey thanks for your help! I tried your solution, but it didn't print anything

Comment: full json here: http://virtualflight.ddns.net/api/weather.php?icao=ehrd

Answer (score 1):

Correct json

```
{
    "title": [
        [
            "Temperature",
            " ",
            "Good"
        ],
        [
            "Visibility",
            "10 KM (6.2 Mi)",
            "Good"
        ]
    ]

}
```

---

```
var arr = [WeatherItem]()
do {
     let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:[[String]]].self, from: data)
     let content = res["title"]!
     content.forEach {
       if $0.count >= 3 {
         arr.append(WeatherItem(title:$0[0],value:$0[1],condition:$0[2]))
       }
     }
     print(arr)
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

**Discussion :** your root object is a dictionary that contains 1 key named `title` and it's value is an array of array of strings or from the model logic it's an array of model named `WeatherItem` but isn't structured properly for it ,  so using this

```
let weather = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherItem.self, from: data)
```

won't work as the current json does't contain keys `value` and `condition`

A proper strcuture would be

```
[
    {
        "title":"Temperature" ,
        "value":"",
        "condition":"Good"
    },
    {
        "title":"Visibility",
        "title":"10 KM (6.2 Mi)",
        "condition":"Good"
    }
]
```

and that will enable you to do

```
let weather = try JSONDecoder().decode([WeatherItem].self, from: data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write the decoding initializer by yourself:

```
struct WeatherData: Decodable {
    let title: [WeatherItem]
}

struct WeatherItem: Decodable {
    let title: String?
    let value: String?
    let condition: String?

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // decode the value for WeatherItem as [String]         
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let components = try container.decode([String].self)

        title = components.count > 0 ? components[0] : nil
        value = components.count > 1 ? components[1] : nil
        condition = components.count > 2 ? components[2] : nil
    }
}

let json = """
{
  "title": [
     ["Temperature", "9", "Good"],
     ["Visibility", "10 KM (6.2 Mi)", "Good"]
   ]
}
"""

let jsonData: Data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

let decoded = try! decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: jsonData)
debugPrint(decoded)
```

Comment: but the JSON info is always changing.

Comment: @DylanStrijker The structure changes? You haven't specified that in your question! That it would be probably better for `WeatherItem` to just hold `[String]`? It's unclear what is the format of the data and what operations you are doing on them.

Comment: I meant the info always changes. Like, the word temperaturen will be the same, but the second string will chnage.

Comment: @DylanStrijker I don't see the problem then. I have just used that JSON as an example how to parse the data. I thought that would be obvious.

Comment: okay thanks! Your example works, but I would like to use this link: http://virtualflight.ddns.net/api/weather.php?icao=ehrd how can I do it with a link? I am beginner with JSON parsing